# while swiping the tabs ,oncreateView of Fragment is not called,how to call oncreateView every time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs and i am using `fragments`.When the `activity` is first time called all the 3 fragments are generated. i have some check boxes on `fragment1` and when I perform some actions on `fragment1` and swipe, I want to call `oncreateView` of `fragment3` again? 
Whenever i swipe or click on the tabs i want oncreateview called again as i am generating the `fragment3` UI dynamically.
If I go back to `fragment1` and then come back to `fragment3` ,i am seeing the changes.

a) My activity is extending `FragmentActivity`

```
public class AddProgramActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener
```

b) Adapter class is extending `FragmentPagerAdapter`

c) and my fragment classes are extending `Fragment`.

Please suggest how I can force my fragment 3 `oncreateView` is called every time I swipe or click on the tab or how to refresh every time I swipe.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem like yours. My situation is trying to set back flags to disable the ActionBar buttons and call the `invalidateOptionsMenu` every time the view is created.

I have 3 tabs (corresponding to 3 fragments) on the actionbars. If I select from tab 1 to tab 2 and back to tab 1, then `onCreateView` of tab 1 is not called, but if I select from tab 1 to tab 3 and back to tab 1, then `onCreateView` of tab 1 is called

I cannot find any solution for this. My workaround is setting back the flags and call `invalidateOptionsMenu` in the function `onTabSelected` of `TabListener`

Somethings like this

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        MainFragmentActivity.disableBookmarkFlag = MainFragmentActivity.disableShareFlag = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    .....
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Did this work? I tried using the OnResume method although it doesn't seem to work as intended. Would this be the best work around? It seems a little excessive for something that should be fundamentally easy

Comment: yes @RandyFreak, it works for me, though I still looking around